# Machine Learning Algorithm for Predicting Indoor Temperature

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I have hourly weather data from outside and hourly weather data from inside a room in a house. I also have hourly weather data for 2 days into the future for outside. Assuming no air conditioner or heater, what would be a good machine learning algorithm for predicting the temperature of the room inside the house for one day in the future? I also have humidity for outside and indoor. And cloud cover for outside.

There's one factor that can't be tracked which is the windows in the room will be opened or closed sometimes. However, I'm hoping the algorithm will find a trend over time.

Comment: The intuitive approach is a supervised-learning approach (like mentioned by @Ёжик в тумане), but mostly a model-based instead of a model-free approach (Linear Regression assumes, that the model follows linearity; which is quite a bad assumption here; but nontheless Linear Regression is always a good first step). A very good approach would be to use nonlinear-optimization on your data following a model describing newton's law of cooling (room heats up nonlinearily faster if difference to outside is higher). It might be possible to introduce more model-assumptions (like window-sun-angle).

Comment: About half the heat exchange of an office building is due to air infiltration/exfiltration.  The other half is due to sunlight.  So I think you need to add sunrise/sunset to your data to improve your model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to predict a value like room temperature based on room temperature in the past this is a [supervised learning](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) task. You could use `linear regression`, which is a statistical method to predict continuous data. You can find a description at the open classroom of Stanford University for example.
[Linear Regression](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex2/ex2.html)

[image: Source: Stanford Open Classroom]